# Delete multiple textboxes from list of controls

Tags: vb.net, textbox, controls

I have a list of controls created dynamically in a control list. The user has options to add `textboxes` in the control list and to delete them as well.

I have created the `textboxes` using the following code:

```
Dim tb As New TextBox
tb.Name = "Textbox" & counter.ToString
tb.Left = 55
tb.Top = fields
Me.Controls.Add(tb)
MyControls.Add(tb)
counter = counter + 1
```

So, the `textbox` names when created are `Textbox1`, `Textbox2` and so on maximum up to `Textbox10`.

The user can delete `textboxes` by button clicks one by one. If the user wants to delete these `textboxes`, `counter` will run backward and will delete `Textbox10` first and then `Textbox9` and so on (This is the same as First in First Out).

So, for deleting I tried the following code, but it didn't execute, giving an error. The code is written under Button's Click event of the delete button.

```
For Each CType(Me.Controls("Textbox" & counter), TextBox) As Control In MyControls
     Me.Controls.Remove(...) 'The textbox's name to be deleted in place of dots
     'The textbox name to be deleted here with .Dispose()
Next
```

The error is: "Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment" in the first line of the above code.

**How to delete a series of `textboxes` dynamically?**

Comment: "but it didn't execute, giving an error." -- and the error is?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to write the error - "Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment."

Comment: Please don't post it in comments--update the question.  Also, where exactly (on what line) is it occurring?

Comment: Already did it, okay. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is causing the problem:

```
For Each CType(Me.Controls("Textbox" & counter), TextBox) As Control In MyControls
```

`CType(Me.Controls("Textbox" & counter), TextBox)` resolves to a value, so it cannot be a loop increment variable.

To delete based on a loop, you would need to know how many controls you want to delete. Here is one way:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To Math.Min(NumberOfControlsToDelete, 10) ' Cap deleting at 10.
    ' Make sure we don't go below 1.
    If counter < 1 Then Continue

    ' Expected that the control will exist.
    Me.Controls.Remove(Controls.Find("TextBox" & counter, True)(0))
    ' Decrement counter.
    counter -= 1
Next
```

Comment: It gives an error- "Argument not specified for parameter 'searchAllChildren' of 'Public Function Find(key As String, searchAllChildren As Boolean) As System.Windows.Forms.Control()'." but looks like this is something related to what I need.

Comment: @Error404 - I always forget that param. I updated the answer.

Comment: There still is an error. I took much time to revise, but of no help. "Value of type '1-dimensional array of System.Windows.Forms.Control' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'." I am really helpless.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're already keeping track of those dynamic buttons by adding them to a List? in this line (your 6th line of code):

```
MyControls.Add(tb)
```

As such, simply grab the last entry and remove it, no need to go searching for the control by name:

```
    If MyControls.Count > 0 Then
        Dim TB As TextBox = MyControls(MyControls.Count - 1)
        MyControls.Remove(TB)
        TB.Dispose()
    End If
```

If you want to delete all of them at the same time:

```
    For Each TB As TextBox In MyControls
        TB.Dispose()
    Next
    MyControls.Clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?  I'm not sure I'm reading your question correctly.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Controls.Remove(Me.Controls.Find(""Textbox" & counter"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Sort of. But it gives an error- "Argument not specified for parameter 'searchAllChildren' of 'Public Function Find(key As String, searchAllChildren As Boolean) As System.Windows.Forms.Control()'." What should I do here? Thank you.